# String.Format failing with strange error

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, string.format

I have a method running with the following code:

```
private void WriteToDb()
{
    using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(_conStr))
    {
        dbConnection.Open();
        using (SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(_conStr))
        {
            sbc.DestinationTableName = "tblLog";
            try
            {
                sbc.WriteToServer(_tblLog);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} Error writing log info: {1} \n {3}", DateTime.Now.ToString(), e.Message, e.StackTrace));
            }
        }
    }

    _tblLog.Rows.Clear();
}
```

I am receiving an exception from the `String.Format()` method with the following stack trace:

> Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
>   at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
>   at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
>   at System.String.Format(String format, Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2)
>   at MyCompany.MyClient.MySoftware.Logger.WriteToDb()

I can really see the source of this error. As far as I see I am not using any collection in that method. I also have to munch that this method is multi-threaded, but again I could not think of a possible impact.

Thank you!

Comment: `"{0} Error writing log info: {1} \n {3}"` obvious, no?

Comment: sometimes it is very weird where not paying enough attention could lead

Comment: Sorry for the question, I tried to delete it but it is answered and cannot be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} Error writing log info: {1} \n {3}", DateTime.Now.ToString(), e.Message, e.StackTrace));
```

Should be

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} Error writing log info: {1} \n {2}", DateTime.Now.ToString(), e.Message, e.StackTrace));
```

Answer (score 8):

Your last format number is `{3}` instead of `{2}`

Answer (score 1):

You're using `{3}` instead of `{2}`:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} Error writing log info: {1} \n {2}", DateTime.Now.ToString(), e.Message, e.StackTrace));
```

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I see I am not using any collection in that method.

`System.String.Format(String format, Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2)` calls `System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)` so thats where the `Collection` comes into the stack.

As others explained you are using `{3}` but the array has only three elements, at index `0` through `2`